# Method in class can't access arraylist from same class

Tags: java

I don't understand why but my method can't access the arraylist. When I try to add from input it says error: cannot find symbol.

```
    public class Kitchen{
        public static void Kitchen(String[] args ){
        ArrayList<String> Utensil = new ArrayList<String>();
        Utensil.add("Knife"); 
        Utensil.add("Boiler"); 
        System.out.println(Utensil);
        }
       
        public void addUtensil(){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Utensil to add? ");
            String new = sc.nextLine();
            Utensilio.add(new);
       }
    }
```

Comment: The `Utensil` _local variable_ is scoped to the `Kitchen` method, not the class. Also keep in mind that one method is static while the other is not. Also, are you sure that method shouldn't be named `main`?

Comment: You can't name a variable `new` (at least not in java 1.8), it is a java keyword. You should rename that variable.

Comment: The static Method Kitchen is utterly misleading. Methods should be lowercase. Methods better do not have the same name as the enclosing class, at least if they aren't factory methods, which would then produce an instance of the class. The bad naming lead to that kind of failures - wrong assumptions about the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the Utensil ArrayList as a parameter to the addUtensil() method.

```
public static void Kitchen(String[] args ){
    ArrayList<String> Utensil = new ArrayList<String>();
    Utensil.add("Knife"); 
    Utensil.add("Boiler"); 
    addUtensil(Utensil);
    System.out.println(Utensil);
    }

 public static void addUtensil(List<String> Utensil){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Utensil to add? ");
        String new = sc.nextLine();
        Utensilio.add(new);
}
```

Comment: Since `addUtensil` is an instance method you would need to either do `new Kitchen().addUtensil(Utensil)` or make the method static.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different methods

1. Kitchen
2. addUtensil

you declared a below local variable in one method(Kitchen) and trying to access on other method(addUtensil).

```
ArrayList<String> Utensil = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In java you can not access the local variable of one method to another

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define it as an class variable, remember that we can access a static variable via not static method,but on the other side it's not

```
   public class Kitchen{
        
        private static ArrayList<String> Utensil = new ArrayList<String>();

        public static void Kitchen(String[] args ){
          Utensil.add("Knife"); 
          Utensil.add("Boiler"); 
          System.out.println(Utensil);
        }
       
        public void addUtensil(){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Utensil to add? ");
            String new = sc.nextLine();
            Utensilio.add(new);
       }
    }
```